# Add smooth transition between images switching React carousel

Tags: next.js, carousel, swiper.js

I implement image carousel and want to add smooth transition when image change. So when i click on next button the image smoothly animate and place on 1st image. like in the demo. Design and functionality is already implemented but face an issue while implementing transition like in demo.

Demo:
[Demo](https://swiper-component.vercel.app/)

Code:
**Home.jsx**

```js
"use client";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useState } from "react";
import { imagesUrls } from "./config/constat";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import { Pagination } from "swiper/modules";
import { FaArrowLeftLong, FaArrowRightLong } from "react-icons/fa6";

import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/effect-fade";

export default function Home() {
  const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState(0);

  const handleNextClick = () => {
    setCurrentImage((prevImage) =>
      prevImage === imagesUrls.length - 1 ? 0 : prevImage + 1
    );
  };

  const handlePrevClick = () => {
    setCurrentImage((prevImage) =>
      prevImage === 0 ? imagesUrls.length - 1 : prevImage - 1
    );
  };

  const isFirstImage = currentImage === 0;
  const isLastImage = currentImage === imagesUrls.length - 1;

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen justify-between py-20 md:pl-12 px-8">
      <Swiper
        slidesPerView={"auto"}
        spaceBetween={30}
        pagination={{
          clickable: true,
        }}
        modules={[Pagination]}
        className="mySwiper"
      >
        <SwiperSlide key={currentImage}>
          <div className="flex justify-between gap-4">
            <Image
              src={imagesUrls[currentImage]}
              width={1200}
              height={70}
              priority
              alt={`img${currentImage + 1}`}
              className="rounded-2xl w-[1050px] h-[300px] md:h-auto"
            />
            <div className="flex flex-col justify-between w-[300px]">
              <div className="flex items-center justify-center gap-5">
                <button
                  className={`${
                    isFirstImage ? "bg-[#2E3324] text-gray-400" : "bg-[#434B34]"
                  } px-5 rounded-3xl py-1.5`}
                  onClick={handlePrevClick}
                  disabled={isFirstImage}
                >
                  <FaArrowLeftLong />
                </button>
                <p className="text-gray-600 text-sm">{`${currentImage + 1}/${
                  imagesUrls.length
                }`}</p>
                <button
                  className={`${
                    isLastImage ? "bg-[#2E3324] text-gray-400" : "bg-[#434B34]"
                  } px-5 rounded-3xl py-1.5`}
                  onClick={handleNextClick}
                  disabled={isLastImage}
                >
                  <FaArrowRightLong />
                </button>
              </div>
              {!isLastImage && (
                <div
                  className=""
                  style={{ overflow: "hidden", position: "relative" }}
                >
                  <Image
                    src={imagesUrls[currentImage + 1]}
                    width={400}
                    height={300}
                    priority
                    alt={`img${currentImage + 1}`}
                    className="rounded-2xl md:h-[400px] min-w-fit"
                    style={{ marginLeft: "20px" }}
                  />
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </main>
  );
}
```

I already try using **css**, **swiper** and **gsap** but its not working for me.